# PHP progress bar without upload progress-module or APC

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

On my website, users can upload photos. I would like to show them a progress-bar but my server doesn't have the `upload-progress module` or `APC`. Can I make such a thing in pure PHP, JQuery/AJAX?

Comment: Check out this HTML5 File upload article. The only way to have progress bar for upload of file is to use Flash or HTML5 feature like the one described here: http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this script, it is by far the most robust, simplest ajax upload script with progress. It does not have a progress bar though, it returns a percentage which can be repurposed to make a progress bar.

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Just wanted to add: no flash!

Comment: This thing works quite well, I might add. It's also quite extensible.

Comment: Nice! Looks exactly what I need! But my JS knowledges isn't as much as the script requires... Where can I set the path to upload the files?

Comment: It should be handled by the php file that is being called by the javascript